# latest elements in array not found? codewars kata

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm solving the following kata:

Given an input of an array of digits, return the array with each digit incremented by its position in the array: the first digit will be incremented by 1, the second digit by 2, etc. Make sure to start counting your positions from 1 (and not 0).

Your result can only contain single digit numbers, so if adding a digit with it's position gives you a multiple-digit number, only the last digit of the number should be returned.

Notes:
return an empty array if your array is empty
arrays will only contain numbers so don't worry about checking that
Examples

```
[1, 2, 3]  -->  [2, 4, 6]   #  [1+1, 2+2, 3+3]

[4, 6, 9, 1, 3]  -->  [5, 8, 2, 5, 8]  #  [4+1, 6+2, 9+3, 1+4, 3+5]
                                       #  9+3 = 12  -->  2
```

My code:

```
const incrementer = (arr) => {
    if (arr === []) {
        return []
    }
    let newArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        let result = arr[i] + (i + 1)
        newArr.push(result)
        if (newArr[i] > 9 ) {
            let singleDigit = Number(newArr[i].toString().split('')[1])
            newArr.push(singleDigit)
        }
    }
    const filteredArr = newArr.filter(el => el >= 0 && el <= 9)
    return filteredArr
}
```

I can't seem to pass the latest test case, which is the following:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8]), [2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 2]
```

I keep getting back the whole correct array up until the second 0, after which the other numbers, 1,2,2 are missing from the solution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ***so if adding a digit with it's position gives you a multiple-digit number, only the last digit of the number should be returned.*** So if number is 12 then only 2 should be returned right?

Comment: You should not simply push value which are greater than 9 at first place, since you're pushing values and than accessing using i it causing index issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CodeManiac , I understood the issue! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the `filter` only runs at the end, and so when you have done a double push in one iteration (once with the value that has more than one digit, and once with just the last digit), the next iteration will no longer have a correct index for the next value that is being pushed: `newArr[i]` will not be that value.

It is better to correct the value to one digit *before* pushing it to your new array.

Moreover, you can make better use of the power of JavaScript:

- It has a nice `map` method for arrays, which is ideal for this purpose
- Use modulo arithmetic to get the last digit without having to create a string first

Here is the proposed function:

```js
const incrementer = (arr) => arr.map((val, i) => (val + i + 1) % 10);

console.log(incrementer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8]));
```

Answer (score 2):

> ... so if adding a digit with it's position gives you a multiple-digit number, only the last digit of the number should be returned.
> So if the number is 12, it expects only 2 to be added to the array.

So your code should be:

```
if (newArr[i] > 9)
{
    newArr[i] = newArr[i] % 10;   // remainder of newArr[i] / 10
}
```

```js
const incrementer = (arr) => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {   // CHANGE HERE
        return [];
    }
    let newArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
        let result = arr[i] + (i + 1)
        newArr.push(result)
        if (newArr[i] > 9 ) {
            newArr[i] = newArr[i] % 10;   // CHANGE HERE
        }
    }
    const filteredArr = newArr.filter(el => el >= 0 && el <= 9)
    return filteredArr
}

console.log(incrementer([2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 2]));
console.log(incrementer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8]));
```

Comment: You should update this `arr === []` this will always result false, as in JS these are two different memory references.

Comment: @CodeManiac, used `arr.length === 0` check instead. Hope that works.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below code.

```js
const incrementer = arr => {
  if (arr === []) {
    return [];
  }
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let result = arr[i] + (i + 1);
    // newArr.push(result);
    if (result > 9) {
      let singleDigit = Number(result.toString().split("")[1]);
      newArr.push(singleDigit);
    } else {
      newArr.push(result);
    }
  }
  // const filteredArr = newArr.filter(el => el >= 0 && el <= 9);
  return newArr;
};


console.log(incrementer([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8]))
```

Comment: Good one, please update your answer with explanation so that OP can understand where he/she went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
const incrementer = (arr) => {
    if (arr === []) {
        return []
    }
    return arr.map((number, index) => (number + index + 1) % 10);
}
```

Doing the needed additions in (number + index + 1) and % 10 operation will get the last digit.